# Получение информации о товаре с различных сайтов с помощью парсинга

Tags: c#

У меня есть информация о товаре, содержащая в себе наименование бренда, модель и артикул. 
Мне необходимо сделать следующее:
Имеется ссылка на товар, перейдя по этой ссылке, Мы получаем страницу с карточкой товара. Необходимо получить следующую информацию: Бренд, модель и артикул товара(если указан) и цену. Как на различных сайтах с помощью парсинга определить наименование бренда, модель, артикул товара и цену?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz4ZCr6pnXA&t=340s - создания парсера HTML на C#, и дальше вытягиваете нужные вам теги и атрибуты, стоит обратить внимание что на различных сайтах эта инфа может быть в разных тегах.

Comment: Поймите одну простую вещь, каждый сайт - уникален. Он имеет свой шаблон, свои механизмы взаимодействия, свой функционал. Где-то это может быть магазин с корзиной, а где-то это просто агрегатор, который собирает из разных источников информацию и выводит ее. Вот у вас есть например 10 машин на стоянке и 1 ключ, откроете вы все 10 машин или нет? Вот тут также. Вам надо сделать для каждого сайта свой алгоритм (может сайт имеет API, а может там простой HTML, а может нужна авторизация), так просто увы, вы не сделаете подобное.

Comment: А если сайтов тысячи?

Comment: Пишите для тысячи алгоритм, как я и говорил - нету универсальных решений!

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Все страницы HTML имеют DOM структуру (больше информации в гугле по запросу "dom структура html"). Для каждого сайта найдите свой путь к нужной части информации. Для с# есть библиотека HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: А если этих сайтов тысячи?